# Solve the equation $x+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{35}{12}$

Tags: radical-equations

Solve the equation $$x+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\dfrac{35}{12}.$$

The equation is defined for $x\in\left(-\infty;-1\right)\cup\left(1;+\infty\right).$ Now I am thinking how to get rid of the radical in the denominator, but I can't come up with anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

One can use trigonometric functions to avoid squaring both sides to get a degree 4 polynomial. Clearly $x>1$. Let $x=\sec t$, $t\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Then the equation becomes
$$ \sec t+\csc t=\frac{35}{12} $$
or
$$ \frac{\sin t+\cos t}{\sin t\cos t}=\frac{35}{12}. $$
Squaring both sides gives
$$ \frac{1+\sin(2t)}{\sin^2(2t)}=\frac{35^2}{24^2} $$
which is equivalent to
$$ 35^2\sin^2(2t)-24^2\sin(2t)-24^2=0 $$
or
$$ (25\sin(2t)-24)(49\sin(2t)+24)=0. $$
Since $\sin(2t)>0$, one has
$$ \sin(2t)=\frac{24}{25} $$
which gives
$$ \cos(2t)=\pm\frac{7}{25}. $$
So
$$ \cos t=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2t)}{2}}=\frac{3}{5} \text{ or } \frac{4}{5} $$
and hence
$$ x=\frac{5}{3} \text{ or }\frac{5}{4}. $$

Answer (score 4):

After moving the $x$ to the right side and squaring, it's essentially the quartic equation $$144 x^4 - 840 x^3 + 937 x^2 + 840 x - 1225 = 0.$$

This can be factorized over $\Bbb Q$: $$(12x^2 - 35x - 49)(4x - 5)(3x - 5) = 0$$ and you easily get all four real roots from here.

---

EDIT:

I should confess that I didn't do the factorisation by hand. Instead, I used [Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), with the following code (which you can also try on the linked page):

```
R.<x> = ZZ[]
(144*x^4 - 840*x^3 + 937*x^2 + 840*x - 1225).factor()
```

and it gave the result in no time.

Comment: The factorization of such a quartic seems to be a long shot for this OP, and besides this there are two more solutions from that last quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract $x$ from both sides, square it, and then multiply both sides by $x^2-1$.  You’ll get a quartic equation in $x$.

Comment: I can't solve quartic equations either.

Comment: There is a general approach to quartic equations here.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=5/u$ with $0\lt u\lt5$ (there are no solutions with $x\lt0$ since $35/12\gt0$). The equation becomes

$${1\over u}+{1\over\sqrt{25-u^2}}={7\over12}={1\over3}+{1\over4}$$

The solutions $u=3$ and $u=4$ (corresponding to $x=5/3$ and $x=5/4$) are easy to see by inspection.  To show there are no other solutions, it suffices to note that

$$\begin{align}
f(u)=u^{-1}+(25-u^2)^{-1/2}
&\implies f'(u)=-u^{-2}+u(25-u^2)^{-3/2}\\
&\implies f''(u)=2u^{-3}+(25-u^2)^{-3/2}+3u^2(25-u^2)^{-5/2}\gt0
\end{align}$$

so the curve is convex on $(0,5)$ and thus $f(u)$ cannot take any value more than twice.

Comment: This is very nice...but probably too advanced for the OP (by his comments). Important here though, imo, is to explain how to come up with such a substitution $\;u:=\frac5x\;$ ...?? Otherwise it looks like a magics trick, I think. The following decomposition $\;\frac7{12}=\frac13+\frac14\;$ and inspection also look slightly far fetched.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Multiply for $12\sqrt{x^2-1}$ your initial equation,
you have $$12(\sqrt{x^2-1})x+12x=35\sqrt{x^2-1} \iff 12x(\sqrt{x^2-1}+1)=35\sqrt{x^2-1}$$
and square (two times to delete the sqrt) to the left and the right.

$$144x^2(\sqrt{x^2-1}+1)^2=35^2(x^2-1)$$

$$144x^2(x^2-1+1+2\sqrt{x^2-1})=35^2(x^2-1)$$

Comment: Won't we get an equation from a big degree?

Comment: @KaloyanK. Yes, of course. But after you must to do the verify of the solutions in the your equation.

Comment: I can't solve the equation. It's from big degree.

Comment: @KaloyanK. Why?

Answer (score 0):

From the equation solve for $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and get
$$\sqrt{x^2-1} = \frac{x}{\frac{35}{12}-x}$$
now raise to the square and get an equation of degree $4$. Only $2$ of its roots will be roots of the initial equation, since they also include the   roots of $x-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{35}{12}$.

Worth plotting the graph of the function $x + \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ on $(1, \infty)$. It it convex, with a minimum at $\sqrt{2}$, which is in between the roots $\frac{5}{4}$ and $\frac{5}{3}$ of our equation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x>1$. To avoid squaring equations, factorize directly as follows

\begin{align}
0 &=x+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-\frac{35}{12}\\
&= \left(x-\frac{35}{12} + \frac{25}{12x}\right)
 + \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} -\frac{25}{12x}\right)\\
&=\frac1x \left( x^2-\frac{35}{12} x+ \frac{25}{12}\right)
 + \frac{x^2-\frac{25}{12}\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
& =\frac1x \left( x^2-\frac{35}{12} x+ \frac{25}{12}\right)
 + \frac{x^4-\frac{25^2}{12^2}({x^2-1})}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}\left( x^2+\frac{25}{12}\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}\\
& =\frac1x \left( x-\frac{5}{4} \right)\left(x- \frac{5}{3}\right)
 + \frac{(x^2-\frac{25}{16})(x^2-\frac{25}{9} )}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}\left( x^2+\frac{25}{12}\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}\\
& =\frac1x \left( x-\frac{5}{4} \right)\left(x- \frac{5}{3}\right)
\left( 1+ \frac{(x+\frac{5}{4})(x+\frac{5}{3} )}{\sqrt{x^2-1}\left( x^2+\frac{25}{12}\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}\right)\\
\end{align}
which leads to the solutions $x= \frac54,\>\frac53$. (The last factor is always positive.)

Comment: I am not sure I see why $x>1.$ It can also be less than $1.$ The equation is defined for $x\in\left(-\infty;-1\right)\cup\left(1;+\infty\right).$

Comment: @KaloyanK.- note that the $RHS=\frac{35}{12}$ is positive; so $x$ must be as well.

Comment: Why do you add and then subtract exactly $\dfrac{25}{12x}?$ What is the idea behind this?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I don't understand why $x$ must be positive, though. Okay, the $RHS=\dfrac{35}{12}$ is positive, and on the LHS we have the sum of two numbers. Why must they be positive, e.g. $-7+10=3?$

Comment: @KaloyanK. - The LHS is proportional to $x$, having its sign as well.

Comment: I see it now. If $x$ is negative, then $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ is also negative, and two negative numbers' sum can't be positive, right?

Comment: @KaloyanK. Correct

Comment: Okay, thank you! But I still don't see why we should add and substract exactly $\dfrac{25}{12x}.$ Can you clarify that to me?

Comment: @KaloyanK. - it ensures that the two groups of terms have common factors to factorize in the end.

Comment: Okay, but how did you come up with it? I mean how did you see it?

Comment: Do you understand my question? I just don't think it's obvious that we must add and then substract $\dfrac{25}{12x}.$ What was your idea behind it?

Comment: Did you use the answers as a reference?

Comment: @KaloyanK. - not obvious to begin with; only after some trial and error

Comment: Okay, but can you explain to me the way to the solution? What did you try before $\dfrac{25}{12x}?$

Comment: @KaloyanK. - I did

Comment: Acc you didn't. Okay, thank you! Happy holidays!

Answer (score -2):

Complete the square.  Then solve to find $x = \dfrac54$ or $x=\dfrac53$.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I see what you mean. Which square am I supposed to complete?

Comment: It is far away from obvious to me...

Comment: Thank you for the diagram, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Very useful graph!  Minimum is at $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @orangeskid Usually a graph is completely useless in this kind of problems (as mathematics schools and teachers don't usually accept them as proof of anything, particularly in high school and undergraduate level), and it may even be contraproducent as some students can get used to see graphs to solve problems...and they don't even know how to graph, it all is online stuff.

Comment: Graphs are some of the best ways to gain intuition and I always urge my students to graph for this reason.  They rarely, if ever, remember some of the more advanced equations, but certainly remember graphs.  Moreover, graphs convey lots of information simultaneously... whether a function is symmetric, its asymptotes, relative locations of extrema and inflection points.  "Useless"?  Hardly.  I'm willing to be that in a month, people who read this question and solution will remember my figure more than they will the algebraic derivations.  Put a reminder in your calendar a month and see!

Comment: Oh... and @DonAntonio:  Please explain your statement on your profile page:  "I hereby shall stop my participation in this site at once."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No, I won't...but it you will I can tell you of users that got banned several times, even for a month, for writing down unappropiate comments. Still, most mathematics depts. I know don't accept graphs as proof of anything... **except** in the very counted cases the students are asked to plot a function's graph AFTER they've researched it...and not using a graphing program.

Comment: Well, if you won't justify or explain your clear and relevant statements after a request, there is no grounds for further discussion.  (Over and out.)